# weird behaviour with yarn vs npm when running vite test

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, vitest

code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitest-dev-vitest-wizy2d?file=package.json

above is the code where running `npm run test` would run all the test.

what i would like is to run a single test using npm example as below

`npm run test -t "Should return posts when clicking fetch button"`

ABOVE DOESNT WORK.

it would still run all the test.

in fact in my local it would not even filter and say you dont have any test with such name.

in the code example in stackblitz it runs all the test.

the behaviour is correct with `yarn` which is puzzling.

QUESTION: why such different behaviour? i would expect with above npm command that it should run single test only.